# MySql syntax error, insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert user inputted values as well as a string that is a combination of the month year of the start date + the user inputted quarter. What is wrong. please help!!!!!

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "addUser")) {
$date=  $_POST['start_date'];
$d=date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d",$date);
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO contacts (USER_NAME, START_DATE, THREE_MONTH, SIX_MONTH, TWELVE_MONTH, QUARTER, ORDER) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,'".$d["month"].$d["year"].$_POST['quarter']."' )",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['start_date'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['3month'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['6month'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['12month'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['quarter'], "text"));
```

error i'm getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER) VALUES ('boobz', '2013-11-22', '2013-11-29',
>   '2013-11-23', '2013-11-02', ' at line 1

Comment: ORDER is a reserved word in SQL. If you really must use it, you'll need to quote it with backticks; but it makes for a much easier time if you avoid naming columns and tables after reserved words in the first place.

Comment: Can you show us, what you have in `$insertSQL` variable?

Comment: @andrewsi Why not make an answer?

Comment: @Shredder - I can generally only pop on to SO for a couple of minutes now and again; I don't like putting up a half-hearted answer, so I mostly stick to comments.

Comment: @andrewsi Was as full as the ones below ;) I feel ya tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORDER is reserved word. Use `` ` `` or better change it to something else in database structure. That's better practice.

Answer (score 2):

Order is a reserved word, you need to quote it with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (USER_NAME, START_DATE, THREE_MONTH, SIX_MONTH, TWELVE_MONTH, QUARTER, `ORDER`)
```

Or better yet, do not use the reserved word and use something more sensible.